# 1x1 convolution instead of Global Average Pooling

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, pooling

is it possible and useful to use a 1x1 convolution before the flatten and dense layer instead of the GAP?
The 1x1 conv should theoretically select the most important Feature maps